Why does the IR-spectrum of N-methyl diethanolamine have two peaks in the 1080-1020 cm-1 area?
I found two peaks in the IR-spectrum of N-methyl diethanolamine in the area of 1080-1020 cm-1, while the IR-spectrum of diethanolamine has only one peak in this area:

(Blue is N-methyl diethanolamine, red is diethanolamine, both spectra are from OPUS database)
The presence of this peak in the region of 1050 cm-1 in the spectrum of diethanolamine is explainable: the peak probably refers to vibrations of the C-O bond. Then what does the second peak in the spectrum of N-methyl diethanolamine in this region refer to? Probably, it is somehow related to the hydrogen atom at the nitrogen atom, which is present in the diethanolamine molecule, since the IR spectrum of triethanolamine also has two peaks in this region. But I do not quite understand what exactly explains this effect. Vibrations of which bond cause the presence of the second peak? Maybe it has something to do with resonance phenomena?

Reduced mass for a methyl group vs. a hydrogen on the central N. You're seeing a shoulder for MDEA due to that, and a separation on DEA - is because of what's attached to the N. The linear C-O bond is going to be higher than 1050 wavenumbers, what that is is very likely the C-C-O asymmetric stretching mode.
